# (Agora) agora-rtc-react renewToken() method failed

Tags: chat, voice, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora

First of all, I'm not good at English, so some sentances are strange or rude... Please understand.
I'm new to Agora and using agora-rtc-react for making voice calling with React web. Now I'm trying to renew my agora token that I got issued when entering a voice channel. So using agoraClient's renewToken() method, but it doesn't work. I got the error below.

`Agora-SDK [ERROR]: data: {"code":110,"data":{"error_code":110,"error_str":"error to verify token permission"}} AgoraRTCException: AgoraRTCError UNEXPECTED_RESPONSE: ERR_NO_AUTHORIZED: error to verify token permission`

And here's my code.

```js
useClientEvent(agoraEngine, "token-privilege-will-expire", async () => {
   try {
      console.log("renew token");

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "[[ My Token Server Host ]]",
        undefined,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${tempToken}`,
          },
        }
      ); // succeed
    
      await agoraEngine.renewToken(data.data.token); // failed
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
});
```

Getting new token was succeed, but renew token was failed. I've tried to find any articles or questions but couldn't found. What is wrong and How can I fix this error?

I tried to figure out the token is valid, I used that new token to join the channel and it worked as well. Only Using renewToken() method is problem.

Comment: I found a solution! My token server gave me whitelist-channel token, but for web, whitelist token is not working to renew token!